# Firefox refuses to obey cache headers

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I have been wrestling with an issue where I cannot seem to get Firefox to serve my static content from it's local cache. No matter what I try, I always get a 304 Not Modified and it still checks with the server.

I am making a lot of requests, so just the connection to check if the resource has not been modified is causing performance loss.

Here are the headers I am sending with my response:

[image]

As you can see I am setting the max age quite far out, and I am also setting the expires for two months from the current date.

I am doing this through a Servlet filter in Jetty. The only thing I can think of is the Last-Modified header is causing Firefox to check back with the server and ignore the other headers. However, the last modified is added somewhere in the jetty internals, and I can't remove it.

Here is the jist of the code I am using in my filter (Just trying to get it working with css for now):

```
if(requestURI.endsWith(".css")){
            Calendar inTwoMonths = Calendar.getInstance();
            inTwoMonths.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Date", new Date().getTime());
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", inTwoMonths.getTimeInMillis());
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-control", "max-age=36000, public");

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you fronting Jetty with another web server, such as nginx?

Comment: I am production but not when I am testing this.